# i am getting keydispatching timed out error on button click in my activity

Tags: android, button, request-timed-out

This is my activity and on the button click i m getting timed out error. the buttons are for openingfone gallery selecting fotos and saving it. pls help me find a solution.

```
Logcat

      08-27 15:57:10.434: E/ActivityManager(80): ANR in com.example.positivityapp (com.example.positivityapp/.CreateSlideActivity)
    08-27 15:57:10.434: E/ActivityManager(80): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

my Activity that contains the buttons.

```
package com.example.positivityapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.positivityapp.db.DBAdapter;
import com.example.positivityapp.views.DraggableGridView;



public class CreateSlideActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> arl;
      Boolean arrsize;
      DraggableGridView dgv;
      ArrayList localArrayList;
      DBAdapter localDBAdapter;
      private FullImageLoader mLoder;
      private Uri musicUrl;
      private TextView textViewMessagetitle;
      boolean url = true;

      private void SaveVideo()
      {
        if (this.musicUrl != null)
        {
          String str = this.musicUrl.toString();
          this.localDBAdapter.addSlideShow(str, this.arl);
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved!", 0).show();
          this.url = false;
          finish();
          return;
        }
        if (this.url) {}
        this.localDBAdapter.addSlideShow(null, this.arl);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved!", 0).show();
        this.url = true;
        finish();
      }
      private void setListeners()
      {
        this.dgv.setOnRearrangeListener(new com.animoto.android.views.OnRearrangeListener()
        {
          public void onRearrange(int paramAnonymousInt1, int paramAnonymousInt2)
          {
            String str = (String)CreateSlideActivity.this.arl.remove(paramAnonymousInt1);
            if (paramAnonymousInt1 < paramAnonymousInt2)
            {
              CreateSlideActivity.this.arl.add(paramAnonymousInt2, str);
              return;
            }
            CreateSlideActivity.this.arl.add(paramAnonymousInt2, str);
          }
        });
        this.dgv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAnonymousAdapterView, View paramAnonymousView, int paramAnonymousInt, long paramAnonymousLong)
          {
            CreateSlideActivity.this.dgv.removeViewAt(paramAnonymousInt);
            CreateSlideActivity.this.arl.remove(paramAnonymousInt);
          }
        });
      }

      protected void onActivityResult(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, Intent paramIntent)
      {
        super.onActivityResult(paramInt1, paramInt2, paramIntent);
        if ((paramInt2 == -1) && (paramIntent != null))
        {
          if (paramInt1 != 1) {
              for (;;)
            {

              if (paramInt1 == 0)
              {
                this.localArrayList = ((ArrayList)paramIntent.getSerializableExtra("list"));
                if (this.arl == null)
                {
                  this.arl = this.localArrayList;
                  this.arrsize = Boolean.valueOf(true);
                }
                if (this.arrsize.booleanValue())
                {
                  int k = 0;
                  if (this.localArrayList != null)
                  {
                    this.textViewMessagetitle.setVisibility(0);
                    this.dgv.setVisibility(0);
                    this.arl.addAll(this.localArrayList);
                    k = this.localArrayList.size();
                  }
                  for (int m = 0;; m++)
                  {
                    if (m >= k / 2)
                    {
                      this.arrsize = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                      return;
                    }
                    this.localArrayList.remove(m);
                    ImageView localImageView2 = new ImageView(this);
                    localImageView2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    localImageView2.setImageBitmap(this.mLoder.getBitmap((String)this.localArrayList.get(m), 300, 300));
                    this.dgv.addView(localImageView2);
                  }
                }
                if (this.localArrayList == null) {
                  break;
                }
                this.textViewMessagetitle.setVisibility(0);
                this.dgv.setVisibility(0);
                this.arl.addAll(this.localArrayList);
                int i = this.localArrayList.size();
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                  ImageView localImageView1 = new ImageView(this);
                  localImageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                  localImageView1.setImageBitmap(this.mLoder.getBitmap((String)this.localArrayList.get(j), 300, 300));
                  this.dgv.addView(localImageView1);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          this.musicUrl = paramIntent.getData();
        }

      }
      public void onBackPressed()
      {
        super.onBackPressed();

      }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_slide);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoosePictures);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMusic);
        Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPreview);
        Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
           startActivityForResult(new Intent().setClass(CreateSlideActivity.this, MultiPhotoSelectActivity.class), 0);
          }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent();
            localIntent.setType("audio/*");
            localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
            CreateSlideActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Complete action using"), 1);
          }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
            if (CreateSlideActivity.this.arl == null)
            {
              Toast.makeText(CreateSlideActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Choose photos from gallery!", 0).show();
              return;
            }
            Intent localIntent = new Intent();
            localIntent.putExtra("list", CreateSlideActivity.this.arl);
            localIntent.setData(CreateSlideActivity.this.musicUrl);
            localIntent.putExtra("preview", true);
            localIntent.putExtra("oldslide", false);
            localIntent.setClass(CreateSlideActivity.this, SlideShow.class);
            CreateSlideActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
          }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
            if (CreateSlideActivity.this.arl == null)
            {
              Toast.makeText(CreateSlideActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Choose photos from gallery!", 0).show();
              return;
            }
            CreateSlideActivity.this.localDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(CreateSlideActivity.this);
            CreateSlideActivity.this.SaveVideo();
          }
        });
       this.dgv = ((DraggableGridView)findViewById(R.id.vgv));
        this.textViewMessagetitle = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMessagetitle));
        this.mLoder = new FullImageLoader(getBaseContext(), (short)200);
        setListeners();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_slide, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 

    android:padding="2.0dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:keepScreenOn="true"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/layout_button" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad1">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonChoosePictures" 
                android:background="@drawable/ingallery" 
                android:layout_width="100.0dip" 
                android:layout_height="100.0dip" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonMusic" 
                android:background="@drawable/inmusic" 
                android:layout_width="100.0dip" 
                android:layout_height="100.0dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonPreview" 
                android:background="@drawable/inpreview" 
                android:layout_width="100.0dip" 
                android:layout_height="100.0dip" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonSave" 
                android:background="@drawable/insave" 
                android:layout_width="100.0dip" 
                android:layout_height="100.0dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
                android:id="@+id/textViewMessagetitle" 
                android:visibility="gone" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip" 
                android:text="Drag slide to arrange slide" />
            <com.example.positivityapp.views.DraggableGridView 
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" 
                android:id="@+id/vgv" 
                android:background="@drawable/bg_grid" 
                android:visibility="gone" 
                android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```